# Join table results Google BigQuery

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I have two SQL queries:

```
SELECT subreddit, count(subreddit) as count
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.all] 
where author="***********" GROUP by subreddit ORDER BY count DESC;
```

AND

```
SELECT subreddit, count(subreddit) as count
FROM [redditcollaborativefiltering:aggregate_comments.reddit_posts_all]
where author="***********" GROUP by subreddit ORDER BY count DESC;
```

I want to be able to join the results of both of these queries into one result with the same columns as both, however, the count is summed with each other. Is there any easy way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BigQuery Legacy SQL (that I see you use in your example) you can use below:

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT subredit, SUM(cnt) as cnt
FROM (SELECT subreddit, COUNT(subreddit) as cnt
       FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.all] 
       WHERE author = '***********'
       GROUP BY subreddit 
      ),
      (SELECT subreddit, COUNT(subreddit) as cnt
       FROM [redditcollaborativefiltering:aggregate_comments.reddit_posts_all] 
       WHERE author = '***********'
       GROUP by subreddit
      )
GROUP BY subreddit
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

As you can see here - comma in Legacy SQL is used as UNION ALL

Above can be further simplified

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT subreddit, COUNT(subreddit) as cnt
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.all],
  [redditcollaborativefiltering:aggregate_comments.reddit_posts_all]
WHERE author = '***********'
GROUP BY subreddit 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

You can read more about [`Comma as UNION ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql#comma_as_union_all) for BigQuery Legacy SQL

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` and another aggregation:

```
SELECT subredit, SUM(cnt) as cnt
FROM ((SELECT subreddit, count(subreddit) as cnt
       FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.all] 
       WHERE author = '***********'
       GROUP BY subreddit 
      ) UNION ALL
      (SELECT subreddit, count(subreddit) as cnt
       FROM [redditcollaborativefiltering:aggregate_comments.reddit_posts_all]
       WHERE author = '***********'
       GROUP by subreddit
      )
     ) sc
GROUP BY subreddit
ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```